# How to write remote hook for a method with parameter and relation

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs, strongloop

I went through the remote hook [documentation](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Remote+hooks), I can successfully create remote hooks for methods without extra parameters, like `login`,
which is:

```
customer.afterRemote('login', function(ctx, modelInstance, next) {
      if (ctx.result) {
          ...
          next();
      }
      else{
          next();
      }
    });
```

Now, How to write a remote hook for a method say :

```
GET /customers/{id}

POST /customers/{id}
```

or
while posting related objects like

```
POST /customers/{id}/contacts
GET /customers/{id}/contacts
```

I know doing the following with `POST /customers/{id}/contacts`:

```
customer.beforeRemote('**', function(ctx, user, next) {
  console.log(ctx.methodString, 'was invoked remotely'); // customers.prototype.save was invoked remotely
  next();
});
```

would return the name of the method called like:

> customer.prototype.__create__contacts was invoked remotely

But I am still unable to hook it specifically, and following tries are to no avail, and hook isn't being reached:

```
customer.beforeRemote('customer.prototype.__create__contacts', function(ctx, user, next)

customer.beforeRemote(customer.prototype.__create__contacts, function(ctx, user, next)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out! The answer lies [here](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback/issues/737)

First catch the method name using `customer.beforeRemote('**', function(ctx, user, next)` as I mentioned in question, then simply following would work:

```
customer.beforeRemote('*.__create__assets', function(ctx, user, next) {
      console.log(ctx.methodString, 'was invoked remotely with customers'); // customers.prototype.save was invoked remotely
      next();
    });
```